How can i fill the missing rows of dataframe column using average of another column?
I have a Dataframe with some missing values, I want to fill the missing values instead of dropping them.
But after writing the function, i am getting an error: ['MSSubCLass'] not in index.
LotFrontage is the column I want to fill.
MSSubCLass is the column I want to fill with its averages.




def LotFrontage_fill(columns):
    LotFrontage = columns[0]
    MSSubCLass = columns[1]
    
    if pd.isnull(LotFrontage):
        if MSSubCLass == 20:
            return 75
        elif MSSubCLass == 30:
            return 60
        elif MSSubCLass == 40:
            return 50
        elif MSSubCLass == 45:
            return 55
        elif MSSubCLass == 50:
            return 65
        elif MSSubCLass == 60:
            return 75
        elif MSSubCLass == 70:
            return 65
        elif MSSubCLass == 75:
            return 68
        elif MSSubCLass == 80:
            return 80
        elif MSSubCLass == 85:
            return 70
        elif MSSubCLass == 90:
            return 70
        elif MSSubCLass == 120:
            return 40
        elif MSSubCLass == 160:
            return 20
        elif MSSubCLass == 180:
            return 20
        else:
            return 55
    else:
        return LotFrontage
    
    
train_df.LotFrontage = train_df[["LotFrontage","MSSubCLass"]].apply(LotFrontage_fill, axis = 1)


Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See How to make good reproducible pandas examples for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Is MSSubCLass the correct name? The image shows MSSubClass.

Yes, that's the column name.

You answer to Krishnadev's comment is ambiguous. Is the column name MSSubCLass or MSSubClass? Column name seems to be MSSubClass with a lower L for Class. But your code use MSSubCLass with a upper L for Class. Which matches perfectly well the error you get: there is no column MSSubCLass. For me, the immediate answer is in that comment. You simply mispelled the column name in your code (there might be some other errors, once you'll have corrected this one. But for the error about which you asked the question, that's it)

Thanks, it's actually misspelling error.... I really appreciate you guys assistance.

(Just so that the question can be marked as solved, I repeat my comment here as an answer)
From the images you posted, it looks like you misspelled the column name in your code: It should be MSSubClass with a lowercase l and not MSSubCLass with an uppercase L.

To fill missing values in a DataFrame column using the average of another column, you can follow these steps using Python and pandas:
Calculate the average of the column from which you want to fill missing values.
Use the fillna() method to replace missing values in the target column with the calculated average.
